# How would I make other variables True based on what one variable contains?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I make other variables `True` based on what one variable contains?

Example:
If I have variables:

```
var1 = False
var2 = False
var3 = False
var4 = False
var5 = False
```

And I have this next line of command:

```
components = w.find_element_by_id('components-val')
```

And `components` returns as `1, 3, 5`, How do I make variables `var1`, `var3`, `var5` all `True`?

Same as if I `components` return as `1`, `2` , the variables `var1` and `var2` would be `True`

Comment: [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#"Unasking"_the_question) ‍♂️?! Don't have individual variables in the first place, but have a list like `[1, 3, 5]` and base decisions off of that…?! E.g. instead of `if var1` somewhere, do `if 1 in components`…

Answer (score 2):

You could save the numbers in a `dictionary` and then update it based on your results from `compontents`:

```
true_false = {1: False, 2: False, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False}

components = [1,2,3]

for i in components:
    if i in true_false:
        true_false[i] = True
```

Comment: I accidentally named variables and values as numbers. Is this also possible with string values?